# Problem with publihing velocity,Pioneer 3dx doesnt stop

Tags: ros, publisher, pioneer-3dx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have been trying to move my pioneer from point A to B and return back to point A. I have written a code which starts publishing velocity when the position (x,y,z) is zero. I want it to move to a distance say 0.2m in x direction and stop and then turn and come back to initial position. But the problem is after publishing first velocity command it does not publishes second command i.e. command  to stop.

```
if (linearposx==0)
   {
     Velocity_pub.publish(velocity);
   }
    if(linearposx<=-0.1)
   {
      Velocity_pub.publish(Stop);
   }
```

Here is my complete code:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "nav_msgs/Odometry.h" 
#include <ros/console.h>
#include "geometry_msgs/Pose.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"
#include <tf/transform_datatypes.h>





double quatx;
double quaty;
double quatz;
double quatw;
double linearposx;
double linearposy;



class PioneerData
{
 public: 
 void ComPoseCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg);
};



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    PioneerData pioneer_Data;
    ros::init(argc, argv, "Test_FK"); 
    ros::NodeHandle n;                 
    ros::Publisher Velocity_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/RosAria/cmd_vel",1000);
    ros::Subscriber ComPose_sub = n.subscribe("/RosAria/pose", 1000, &PioneerData::ComPoseCallback, &pioneer_Data);
   
   
    geometry_msgs::Twist velocity;
    velocity.linear.x =0.02;
    velocity.linear.y =0;
    velocity.linear.z =0;
    velocity.angular.x =0;
    velocity.angular.y =0;
    velocity.angular.z =0;
   
    geometry_msgs::Twist Stop;
    Stop.linear.x =0;
    Stop.linear.y =0;
    Stop.linear.z =0;
    Stop.angular.x =0;
    Stop.angular.y =0;
    Stop.angular.z =0;
   

    
  
   //ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
  //ros::Rate rate (1);
  
  while (ros::ok())
   {
    if(Velocity_pub.getNumSubscribers()>0)
    {
    if (linearposx==0)
    {
     
    Velocity_pub.publish(velocity);
     
    }
    if(linearposx>=0.1)
    {
      Velocity_pub.publish(Stop);
    }
    ros::spin();

    //sleep(100);
   //break;
    }
   }
  std::cout<<"xPosition"<<" "<<linearposx<<std::endl;   //ROS_INFO("Position-> x: [%f], y: [%f]",linearposx,linearposy);//return 0;
}

void PioneerData::ComPoseCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg)            
{
    ROS_INFO("Seq: [%d]", msg->header.seq);
    ROS_INFO("Position-> x: [%f], y: [%f], z: [%f]", msg->pose.pose.position.x,msg->pose.pose.position.y, msg->pose.pose.position.z);
    ROS_INFO("Orientation-> x: [%f], y: [%f], z: [%f], w: [%f]", msg->pose.pose.orientation.x, msg->pose.pose.orientation.y, msg->pose.pose.orientation.z, msg->pose.pose.orientation.w);
    
   linearposx=msg->pose.pose.position.x;
   linearposy=msg->pose.pose.position.y;
   quatx= msg->pose.pose.orientation.x;
   quaty= msg->pose.pose.orientation.y;
   quatz= msg->pose.pose.orientation.z;
   quatw= msg->pose.pose.orientation.w;
   
   tf::Quaternion q(quatx, quaty, quatz, quatw);
   tf::Matrix3x3 m(q);
   double roll, pitch, yaw;
   m.getEulerYPR(yaw, pitch, roll); //getRPY
   //ROS_INFO("Yaw: [%f],Pitch: [%f],Roll: [%f]",yaw,pitch,roll);

   return ;
```

}

Edit 1:

Through trial and error I came to know that I am not using ros::spin() or ros::spinOnce correctly. I am getting confused as to where to call ros::spin() or ros::spinOnce.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238934/problem-with-publihing-velocity,pioneer-3dx-doesnt-stop./) by [Tomm](https://answers.ros.org/users/27284/tomm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2016-07-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yep, you are using `ros.spin()` wrong here. You can read up on it in the tutorial here : http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning

Basically a call to `ros.spin()` will sleep until the node is killed. So your loop will not enter the second iteration.
Also you are using the condition `ros.ok()` in your `while` loop. The problem with that is that it will not terminate until the ros node is terminated. So your `cout` will not be executed either.

And I see another logic error. Your global variable `linearposx` is tested in the `while` loop. Now, at the start `linearposx = 0` therefore the `velocity` will be published. When it is published, `linearposx` is set to 0.02. Now, after that, neither `linearposx == 0` or `linearposx >= 0.1` will be evaluated true. You might want to rethink your design.

Hope this solves your problem!

---

Originally posted by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) with karma: 849 on 2016-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tomm](https://answers.ros.org/users/27284/tomm/) on 2016-07-08**:
Thanks man. Code works !!